# Need help lowering memory usage for webpack during deploy/build for an SPA on Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, webpack

Looks like we've outgrown Heroku. But we need to keep using it in the meantime while we find a replacement.

We're starting to continually hit memory limits during deploy:
 `JavaScript heap out of memory`. We've already maxxed out the flag `--max_old_space_size=2560`

We *really* needed to push recently and had to disable sourcemaps just to get it to successfully build.

However we also *really* need sourcemaps.

Can you take a look at our webpack config to see if there is a way to drastically lower memory usage while still keeping sourcemaps?

**Webpack version**

5.27.0

**Command**

`NODE_OPTIONS="--max-old-space-size=2560" webpack --config webpack.config.prod --mode production`

**webpack.config.prod.js**

```
const config = {
  mode: "production",
  //devtool: "source-map",
  context: __dirname,
  entry: {
    // ...entries removed
  },
  output: {
    publicPath: path.join(__dirname, "/builds"),
    path: path.join(__dirname, "/server/public/builds/"),
    filename: "[name].js",
  },
  plugins: [
    new CompressionPlugin(),
    new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/^\.\/locale$/, /moment$/),
    new CleanWebpackPlugin({
      cleanOnceBeforeBuildPatterns: [
        "server/public/builds",
        "server/public/js",
        "server/public/css",
        "server/public/vendor",
      ],
    }),
  ],
  optimization: {
    moduleIds: "named",
    concatenateModules: true,
    minimize: true,
    minimizer: [new TerserPlugin()],
    splitChunks: {
      chunks: "all",
      name: "shared",
      maxAsyncRequests: 20,
      cacheGroups: {
        defaultVendors: {
          test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
          priority: -10,
        },
        default: {
          minChunks: 2,
          priority: -20,
          reuseExistingChunk: true,
        },
      },
    },
  },
};
```